# SQL Error: No column name was specified for column 1 of 'qry'

Tags: sql-server

I get the 'No Column name error' on the qry part of this SQL Query. I have tried  naming the qry column, but did not have any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
WITH qry as ( 
SELECT getdate(), cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 110) as datetime) AS GetDate
      ,T1.[Account] 
      ,t2.AcctName
      ,T1.[RefDate] RefDate
      ,SUM(T1.[Debit])De
      ,SUM(T1.[Credit])Cr
FROM   OJDT T0
       INNER JOIN JDT1 T1
            ON  T0.TransId = T1.TransId
       INNER JOIN oact t2
            ON  t1.Account = t2.AcctCode
                AND t2.Finanse = 'Y'
                AND t2.FrozenFor = 'N'
                AND not t2.AcctName like '%Petty Cash%'
WHERE T1.[RefDate] < CONVERT(date,GETDATE() -7)
GROUP BY
       T1.[Account]
      ,T1.[RefDate]
      ,t2.AcctName
      ) 

SELECT 'TEST' as company
      ,c.Account AS Accountcode
      ,c.AcctName
      ,sum(de) - sum(cr) AS Closing
FROM   qry c
GROUP BY c.Account, c.AcctName
ORDER BY 
  case
    when CHARINDEX('Clearing', c.AcctName) > 1 then 'z'+ c.AcctName
    else c.AcctName
  end
```

Comment: `SELECT getdate(),`: This column needs an alias. Like: `SELECT getdate() as Current_Date,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add name for getdate() column in your cte:

```
WITH qry as ( 
SELECT getdate() AS CurrDate
      , cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 110) as datetime) AS GetDate
      ,T1.[Account] 
      ,t2.AcctName
      ,T1.[RefDate] RefDate
      ,SUM(T1.[Debit])De
      ,SUM(T1.[Credit])Cr
FROM   OJDT T0
       INNER JOIN JDT1 T1
            ON  T0.TransId = T1.TransId
       INNER JOIN oact t2
            ON  t1.Account = t2.AcctCode
                AND t2.Finanse = 'Y'
                AND t2.FrozenFor = 'N'
                AND not t2.AcctName like '%Petty Cash%'
WHERE T1.[RefDate] < CONVERT(date,GETDATE() -7)
GROUP BY
       T1.[Account]
      ,T1.[RefDate]
      ,t2.AcctName
      )
```